# How to include import files in Meteor compiler plugin?

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

Let's say I have a file `plugin.js`, with the following contents:

```js
class MyCompiler {
  processFilesForTarget(files) {
    files.forEach(file => {
      const output = myExternalFunction(file);
      file.addJavaScript({
        data: output,
        path: `${file.getDisplayPath()}.js`
      });
    })
  }
}

Plugin.registerCompiler({
  extensions: ['rb', 'js.rb'],
  filenames: []
}, () => new MyCompiler());
```

I also have a file `myExternalFile.js`, which is located beside `plugin.js`. I want to import `myExternalFunction` from `myExternalFile` to use in `plugin.js`.

I tried using `import { myExternalFunction } from 'myExternalFile';` but that presents the error `'import' and 'export' may only  appear at the top level (17:0)`.

Using `require` presents this error: `require is not defined`.

And finally, using `Npm.require` won't work because it's not an NPM dependency.

So how do I actually accomplish this?

Comment: what's the issue with just doing the `import` at the top level in the file (on top)? Because that *should* work. Are you trying to optimize for the case where the project doesn't have any `rb` files and hence you could save importing something that you don't need?

Comment: That error using import is what happens when you use import at the top of the file.

Comment: It looks like adding any files to your `sources` in Meteor's `package.js` implicitly loads the file globally, so that looks like it solves my problem. It's just strange.

Comment: That's really odd, because as far as I know `plugin.js` is not a special file. So this file should be processed like any other, and of course you can `import` in a file. I'm assuming the issue is not just that you didn't say `from './myExternalFile';` (i.e., local), right?